# python regular expression group string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nsregularexpression

I have a string like this:

```
data="000000002|ROOT |237277309|000000003|ROOT |337277309|000000004|ROOT |437277309|"
```

is there any way I can group it like this except use split,the reason why I don't use split('|') is because split will generate too many list it will cost memory when the list is too large :

```
[[000000002,ROOT,237277309],[000000003,ROOT,337277309],[000000004,ROOT,437277309]]
```

Maybe some code like this:

```
import re
ROOT count left '|' night digt
```

Comment: This is not a regex problem.  Just use `split` (and `strip`) and pull off the pieces 3 at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using this regex:

```
(\d+)\|(ROOT)\s*\|(\d+)(?=\|)
```

**[As you can see here](https://regex101.com/r/LaLtUO/1)**.

---

## Here's the complete code:

```
import re

data="000000002|ROOT |237277309|000000003|ROOT |337277309|000000004|ROOT |437277309|"

print(re.findall(r'(\d+)\|(ROOT)\s*\|(\d+)(?=\|)', data))
```

Which outputs: `[('000000002', 'ROOT', '237277309'), ('000000003', 'ROOT', '337277309'), ('000000004', 'ROOT', '437277309')]`

---

## Explanation:

Capturing groups are your best friends. By placing each term (`\d+` and `ROOT`) in parentheses, you can tell the regex to match them, but also to store their values separately, which results in exactly the output you wanted.

**A quick note**: I used a positive lookahead `(?=\|)` basically to tell the regex that the match should be followed by a `|`, but NOT to match the pipe itself.